What, if any, reactions have governments had to the US sending anti-personnel mines to Ukraine?
One item which received relatively limited coverage last week was the Biden administration providing anti-personnel landmines to Ukraine.  There was a lot more "buzz" around Russia's new missile for example.
While the US is not a signatory to the Ottawa Treaty, Ukraine is.
No, not particularly interested in what human rights NGOs have said.  They are predictably negative.  Nor about Russia's opinion - basically any means for Ukraine to defend itself from Russian aggression is inhumane and escalatory, by definition, to Russia.  And Russia has been sowing mines in Ukraine for 2 years so they have little ground to complain.
More into what Western governments have said.
Before asking this question, I did do a little bit of research and my own misgivings have been considerably allayed due to the specific types of mines being sent:

The Biden administration is sending Ukraine antipersonnel mines that have a limited capacity. The so-called nonpersistent mines are electrically fused and powered by batteries. Once the battery runs out, they won’t detonate, and they can become inert in anywhere from four hours to two weeks.

Landmines would seem, by their nature, the ultimate in defensive-only, "good", weapons.  However, the practice is different: the motivation for the Ottawa Treaty was their lethality years after the end of conflicts and resulting deaths and maiming of civilians.  This, cautiously, would not seem to be the case here.

I guess a lot depends on how accurate that statement about their limited life really is. It's not the same for every mine to be inactive and harmless within two weeks, as for 1% to fail to detonate for two years, as for them to contain environmentally harmful substances that persist after inactivity....

I would guess the use mode of those mines would be "deploy, and after deactivation, collect them back." I think making them deactivate is simple enough (batteries don't magically autocharge themselves) to be safe. But even if you have a 100% guarantee that the mines will not explode on its own, you do not want to leave kilograms upon kilograms of high explosive on the field for whoever wants to pick them. The deactivation would make recollection way easier and cheaper.

@Obie2.0 Let's be realistic, 1% failure rates would be negligible considering the dud rate of general ammunition in this war (at some point Russian missile dud rates were claimed to be above 50%).  The French countryside is still seeing people get killed from time to time from WW1 shells.  My concern is more the weakening of the taboo and treaty around the use of antipersonnel landmines, not so much the residual risk if these mines perform as claimed.

I would read the lifetime statement as two separate features mixed together. First, they have a timer that sets them active for anywhere from 4 hours to 2 weeks. Second, they will become inactive when the battery runs out. I would assume the battery lasts a lot longer than 2 weeks.

The question itself finished on a bit of a damp squib - I walked straight through without encountering a single question mark! It seems to be "has any Western government explicitly approved or disparaged the US sending landmines to Ukraine?" I can't find any evidence of commentary myself - I doubt any US-allied government perceives an advantage in commenting now it's an accomplished fact.

According to Reuters photos coming from UAF American Claimore mines were used in Ukraine way before Biden announced this. Reuters later removed this photo from their pages leaving only photo of anti-tank mines so it looks like this event was toned down by political reasons.

@Steve: Found you a question mark -- it's in the title.  (Agreed, that's poor practice for posing a question)

@user13964273 A claymore mine is not a landmine in the general usage of the word.  It is a remotely-detonated, human-activated, directional "mine" that sprays shrapnel in an arc to its front.  It is not something that sits in the ground, inert and unsupervised until someone - perhaps a civilian - steps on it years later.  France, for example, which has signed the Ottawa treaty still employs an equivalent.

@ItalianPhilosopher, the principle for that distinction isn't clear. Claymores can certainly be set on tripwires or pressure pads, and concealed (for example, behind thin panels in the structure of the built environment) - they are just, in a sense, "above-ground, cross-blasting" landmines. Whether the trigger is manned or not is completely discretionary.

@Steve Again, claymore equivalents are still deployed by Ottawa signatories.

@ItalianPhilosopher, I imagine they just don't define the Claymore as a landmine, because that is not its exclusive configuration. I was just emphasising to you that it can be used in that configuration, and it differs from a landmine only in the sense it is not generally deposited in soil, not in the sense that it must be manned. It's functionally a landmine designed for the urban environment rather than the open countryside.

@ItalianPhilosopher They may have multiple activation methods, but usually set up as a bobby trap for anyone who walks nearby. You physically cannot watch and fire individually all hundreds mines in the field kilometers away from your position.

All weapons that employ primary or secondary explosives have dud rates. The use of any explosive in war results in potential threat of killing or maiming civilians after the war. Secondary explosives are safer, as they're more stable, but also remain lethal for longer. Anti-personnel mines have a tendency to remain dangerous for very long periods of time with a low chance of nature detonating or disarming it. Above ground placement, remote trigger, and/or battery powered triggers all reduce long-term danger, but don't eliminate it. There is no such thing as a safe explosive.

Not exactly an answer, but Finland is looking to exit the Ottawa convention https://yle.fi/a/74-20126703

Any explosive can be rigged to be victim-activated. Claymore isn't the only weapon that can be used other than intended.

It is being discussed. The Anti-Personnel Mine Ban convention meanwhile has issued the following statement:

26 November 2024: Statement Regarding the Possible Transfer of Anti-Personnel Mines to a State Party to the Convention
In the 25 years since the Convention entered into force, this landmark humanitarian disarmament treaty had never faced such a challenge to its integrity.
The announcement by the United States (US) – not a member of the Convention – on the transfer of “non-persistent anti-personnel landmines” (https://www.state.gov/the-united-states-announces-significant-new-military-assistance-for-ukraine-2/), is a radical departure from the United States’ 30-year de facto “anti-personnel landmine policy”.
Article 1 of the Convention stipulates that “Each State Party undertakes never under any circumstances use, develop, produce, otherwise acquire, stockpile, retain or transfer to anyone, directly or indirectly, anti-personnel mines; or assist, encourage or induce, in any way, anyone to engage in any activity prohibited to a State Party under this Convention.”
Article 2 establishes that “an anti-personnel mine [is] one designed to be exploded by the presence, proximity or contact of a person and that will incapacitate, injure or kill one or more persons.”
In its understanding and application, the Convention does not distinguish on the nature of the weapon, whether it is improvised or self-deactivates. The States Parties have agreed that if it fits the definition of an anti-personnel mine as stipulated in Article 2, it is considered an anti-personnel mine and therefore prohibited to a State Party.
Receipt of a prohibited weapon would be a direct violation of the treaty by a State Party.
On this, some delegations to the Siem Reap-Angkor Summit on a Mine-Free World taking place in Cambodia until 29 November, have expressed their concern, noting that it does not matter how they are produced or why they are used (as there are no exceptions on their use) – any use or transfer by States not party to the Convention does not diminish or revoke the obligation of a State Party to uphold its commitments and obligations under the treaty.
All States that have joined have accepted to be bound by these conditions – no exceptions.
While the Ukraine President has acknowledged that Ukraine will receive “essential mines”,  the Ukrainian delegation attending the Summit has not yet informed on this development (https://x.com/ZelenskyyUa/status/1859313020641366485). Ukraine has consistently expressed its commitment to the Convention’s norms, even in the face of unprecedented challenges posed by ongoing conflict.
The Convention has helped establish a strong norm against the use of these weapons – this is reflected by a number of States not party routinely voting in favour of the UN Resolution for the implementation of the Convention. Therefore, any action that challenges this norm is being and should be addressed by the States Parties at the Summit, which is a critical multilateral forum to reaffirm commitments to the principles and objectives of this instrument of international humanitarian law.
The Convention community must remain united in its resolve to uphold the Convention’s norms and principles. This means working collaboratively to address compliance, reaffirming commitments to mine clearance, victim assistance, and mine risk education, and strengthening efforts to universalize the treaty and its norm at the Summit and beyond.
It is important to recall that any use of anti-personnel mines today – anywhere in the world and under any circumstances – will perpetuate suffering for generations and decades to come. These weapons will continue killing and maiming civilians including farmers and children in times of peace. It will be the affected communities which will bear the brunt and pay the heftiest price. Clearing new use will also require substantial resources and place other lives at risk including of those who will have to carry out the dangerous job to remove these weapons from the ground.
In the words of one of the Convention’s greatest champions – Dr Cornelio Sommaruga, the then-President of the International Committee of the Red Cross who died earlier this year,
“World’s governments must now prepare for the ‘long road ahead’, as the daunting challenges of mine clearance and the provision of adequate assistance to all mine victims still have to be addressed. We have learned from the case of landmines that it is both easier and faster to distribute arms than to teach the principles of humanitarian law to those who possess them. If we fail to learn from our mistakes, we are doomed to repeat them”. (Ottawa, 3 December 1997)



... the motivation for the Ottawa Treaty was their lethality years after the end of conflicts and resulting deaths and maiming of civilians. This, cautiously, would not seem to be the case here.

While you are right that the mines are better designed to be demined in the future, I have to point out how all this is still hypocritical.
From a military perspective, there is no doubt that these weapons can help Ukraine impede Russia's recent advancement / incursion into Ukraine due to their revised tactics -  :

“What we've seen most recently is because the Russians have been so unsuccessful in the way that they have been fighting, they've kind of changed their tactics a bit, and they don't lead with their mechanized forces anymore. They lead with the dismounted forces who are able to close and do things to kind of pave the way for mechanized forces,” ...

Thus, Ukranian forces can now use these deadly anti-personnels mines to maim or kill the advancing Russian army on foot, making every such incursion a very deadly affair for the Russian army. This would also force the Russians to pause and refine their tactics.
But, as far as the US is considered, let us recognize that this is another hypocritical demonstration of US policy.
In 2022, the Biden administration rolled back a 2020 Trump-era policy and prohibited the supply and use of anti-personnel mines. They also used this opportunity to claim the "moral" high ground against Russia:

“Neither of these indiscriminate weapons, the horrific consequences of which we are seeing in Ukraine today, belong in the arsenals of civilized nations,” ... Biden administration officials took the opportunity to condemn Russia’s use of land mines in Ukraine, where the munitions “have caused extensive harm to civilians and civilian objects,” Adrienne Watson, a spokeswoman for the National Security Council, said in a statement on Tuesday.

(This kind of flip-flopping of policy, and "might is right" behaviour of the Americans and Russians to push foreign policies whenever it suits their own political interests, is what makes many of us in the "Global South" cynical of superpower politics.)

Do note the Q specifically stated I was not interested in NGO opinions.  They are, almost by definition going to be negative.  My questions was about governments to see if any government was upholding principles over expediency.

@ItalianPhilosopher The Ottawa Convention is a UN treaty with 164 member countries. Thus the statement released by them is on behalf of these 164 countries. Moreover, as stated, this issue has also been raised in the current (and ongoing) international summit on mine ban hosted in Cambodia. If the media bothers to cover what some of these delegates are discussing, we'll know more about the individual stands of some of these member countries.

A couple points of context to add to this answer. 1st, Biden's comments were colored by the fact that there was a lot of photos of grenades and other mines booby-trapping civilian areas. That aside, war conventions are interesting. All of them are the same. Self-imposed restriction X for claimed benefit Y. The prime benefit claimed is moral superiority. Once you see the convention ignored, then you know that they value the combat effectiveness gained is worth more than the supposed benefit of the restriction.

@DavidS This is a needlessly nihilistic viewpoint on arms control.  Most civilized militaries are rather supportive of such endeavors, despite your claims.  Because, at the end of the day, when both sides deploy certain proscribed weapons, the advantages to either side are nullified, leaving mostly misery for victims.   It sounds realistic and it sounds like common sense, and it is also, to me, profoundly repugnant.  Not least because of the military futility of no-holds barred unrestrained warfare.  The world is much better off w.
a ban: civs getting killed decades later does not a war win.

@ItalianPhilosopher: TBH I can't make heads or tails if that website is the official position of the signatories https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/89957/is-apminebanconvention-org-the-official-website-of-the-ottawa-treaty-do-posts-t

@ItalianPhilosopher Firstly, I agree the world is better off with conventions. At the end of the day, war conventions are just self-imposed restrictions for some reason. The conventions vary in adherence and we see in the two most prominent conflicts that one side of the conflict is upholding far fewer conventions than the other. In one case, there is very little to be gained with removing restrictions as there is already too great of a power imbalance. The other conflict sees the weaker side with more restrictions. And there is real benefit to be gained from not following some of them.

@ItalianPhilosopher see my answer to the linked question assessing the role of the ISU in the context of the convention. If you accept that the statement was made in agreement with the meeting in Sien Rep, it needs to be noted that this was a Review Conference, which is an official body of the convention, but not the official meeting of state parties.
