Is apminebanconvention.org the official website of the Ottawa Treaty? Do posts there represent the official opinion of the signatories?
The website apminebanconvention.org has been cited as an official statement by member party states in an answer here. However the Wikipedia page on the treaty doesn't link to this website. So, is it an official site of the Ottawa Treaty? Do statements on that website represent the official join opinion of the signatories of the Treaty?
AFAICT, the site's contact information is

AP Mine Ban Convention Implementation Support Unit 
Geneva International Centre for Humanitarian Demining

The latter is a Swiss non-profit foundation, founded by the Swiss government (according to Wikipedia). So it's rather confusing whom it represents.

re. "cited as an official statement" Even if it is the official organization for the ban, that does not mean it accurately represents the official position of any member government on any particular event/subject, not unless that member government has entrusted them to speak on their behalf.  Would we, for example, expect the Paris Agreement bureaucracy running the show in national countries, CO2 wise?

@ItalianPhilosopher: I'm not sure if this Ottawa Treaty even has an official bureaucracy. Most treaties don't.

The Wikipedia page on the Geneva International Centre for Humanitarian Demining sums it up nicely:

...The GICHD has observer status at the States Parties meetings of the [Mine Ban] Convention.
Since 1999, the GICHD has supported the implementation of the Convention, primarily by hosting meetings of the Standing Committees established by the Convention’s States Parties. In September 2001, the States Parties mandated the GICHD to provide enhanced support to their efforts through the establishment of an Implementation Support Unit (ISU). The ISU's duties include providing support and advice to the Presidency of the Meetings of the State Parties and to Standing Committee Co-chairs, communicating information about the Convention and its implementation, and developing and maintaining a Documentation Centre...

The Implementation Support Unit, whos website you asked about, has a specific mandate by the member states of the convention. The scope of that mandate is detailed here. For example it states that the ISU serves as intersessional secretariat between the official meetings of the members.
The paragraph on "Mandate and Activities: Universalisation" talks about communication:

The ISU supports the President's Mandate including by providing background information, disseminating communication on behalf of the Convention, developing/coordinating universalization strategies, and carrying out follow-up actions.

Even more is listed under "Serves as the authoritative information source on the Convention, keeps records including through a Documentation Centre, coordinates and liaises: Communicating about the Convention":


Authoritative Information: By virtue of its mandate, the ISU serves as the authoritative information source on the Convention and makes available, or is in position to provide upon request, information on the status and implementation of the Convention which may be required by States Parties, the media, academics and students, and others.

Publications: The ISU produces publications on the Convention and in support of the Convention’s meetings. The ISU has produced important reference publications which contain compilations of the victim assistance and mine clearance understandings adopted by the States Parties.



Unfortunately, the links in the website for the original mandate texts are broken, but they can be found via archive.org:

2001 original mandate
2011 revised agreement

